# Flexing in the boards where my studs should be

Tags: studs

I am putting up a TV Wall Mount on a wall in my basement.  I used a stud-finder to find the appropriate places to drill, and lined everything else up with a level.  The stud-finder showed me the 2 places, the appropriate 16" apart.

The problem is, when I drilled into these places, while I definitely felt like there was something beyond the drywall to drill through, there was some "bend" or "flex" to whatever it was.  It was definitely harder to drill through than the drywall itself, but I am pretty sure it was not a full-on stud.  This is a semi-interior wall, given there's a closet behind half of it, and behind the other half of it is the ground.

My questions are as follows:

What do you think I hit? It's kind of odd, but it seems like whatever I drilled into is actually thinner than a stud.  I'm hoping I didn't do something really stupid like drill into a water pipe... but there was no water or anything that came out of it, so I do not think that this is the case.

The TV I'm mounting is a 65" flat screen, weighing approximately 61 pounds. Am I insane for thinking I can still put the TV on the wall like this? I was able to lift myself off the ground and hold myself for a few seconds, and the mount didn't shift at all (and I weigh a hell of a lot more than a TV).

The alternative I guess is to set it on the TV stand, but it's large enough that I'm not 100% sure that it'll fit (need to measure) and I'd like to still be able to secure it to the wall to a degree to help prevent it from falling over (say, on top of a roaming child).

I feel like what I've done now is good enough for a 60 pound TV (4 lag bolts, all secured in these "bendy" studs) but I wanted to get some more opinions and see if someone knew for sure what was going on before I did something stupid.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you catch the edge of the stud ? Are your studs metal studs (newer construction) ? Did you have any wires in that area (like wires traversing down the stud ? You probably hit a Wire. Use that new fangled see through walls tool that has an android app - I think it is $79 bucks on special  - it will allow you to see what is behind that wall. Your stud finder - you should have checked for studs further out - just to be sure you saw center of stud and not wire against the stud.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I hit a wire.  I did measure across the entire wall for studs and found one at the corner (where the light switch is), and 3 more, each 16" apart from each-other.  I measured to half way between where my studfinder said the stud started and stopped.  I'll have another look, though.  Construction is 2005.  Metal detector on finder did not beep.  I'll take a look into this "see through walls tool"

Comment: Did you watch the material the drill was expelling?

Comment: I looked close and did not notice a change in the kind of shavings that were coming out.  I made sure to keep an eye out for plastic.  All I feel like I saw was more white from the dry wall and some insulation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the HVAC pipe, I don't think I can spend $160+ on a fancy see-through-wall-tool (Canada) so I'll be borrowing a better stud finder, and probably cutting a hole in the wall to see what's what.

Comment: In basements, I have seen the use of metal studs to avoid having to use treated wood or metal studs in conjunction with wood which may explain the flex and the thin feel of the material.  My other thought is that I have thin firring strips used a lot in basements but you should have felt your bit hit concrete or block after you went through the thin material.    Hope you will post when you find out what it was, just for my curiosity.

Comment: I've got a buddy coming over with an IR camera tonight, so I'll definitely update this with our findings :)